# Setting up Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am trying to setup the "[Merchant SDK](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant)" for Express Checkout option with Paypal.

While installing the 'dependecy' as prescribed with curl or composer, the system is having trouble with loading 'sqlsrv' and some other modules.

My doubt : Is this all really necessary? Can't I just download the SDK files from github and start using them? The only dependency needed for the basic working is openssl. Am I right about it? What is it that curl/composer really do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

curl is utility to transfer data with different protocols and composer is a php dependency manager which helps in deployment of php code and makes sure that you have the required libraries. You can surely use the code directly but it might become difficult to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use their SDK it's recommended that you use composer to install their package.  That's the only way you'll be able to follow along nicely with all their samples/tutorials.

curl is going to be required to make POST calls to PayPal, but it's generally enabled by default on any good web host.  The composer file is just ensuring that it is available when it installs the package.  The way they built their SDK's does make it a little tough to use without following those procedures.

If you want something a little more direct you might be interested in my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It requires curl, too, but again  you should already have that, and it comes complete with functional samples and prepared template files for all of the API calls PayPal provides.  You can take care of pretty much any API call you need in a matter of minutes.